# Tooltip for button

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc-3

I have button in my MVC 3 view. Here it is:

```
  <button rowId="@employee.Id" value="refresh" class="button-submit" class="btn btn-mini" style="border: 0; background: transparent; box-shadow: none;">
                                <img class="btn btn-mini" width="24" height="24" alt="Delete doctor" src="/Content/img/refresh.png" />
                            </button>
```

I want to show tooltip, so:

```
 $(function () {
        $(".button-submit").tooltip();
    });
```

But is doesn't work in my case. How can I make them work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you import the javascript for the tooltip plugin as well as the JQuery javascript?

Take a look at the example [at the end of this page](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Tooltip/tooltip#options)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" 
                    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/tooltip/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/tooltip/jquery.tooltip.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("a").tooltip();
  });
  </script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="http://jquery.com" title="Write less, do more">jQuery.com</a>
<br/>
<a href="http://learningjquery.com" title="Learn more, write less">learningjQuery.com</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `button` has two `class` attributes, it must only have one.

Comment: Wrong - you [can have multiple classes](http://webdesign.about.com/od/css/qt/tipcssmulticlas.htm). Ids have to be singular. Classes do not.

Comment: Apologies - It's true that you can have multiple but the should be in the same class definition eg `class="a b"` not `class="a" class="b"` - well spotted and +1

Answer (score 0):

try changing `class="button-submit" class="btn btn-mini"` to `class="button-submit btn btn-mini"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<button title="Your tooltip" class="btn btn-default">Add</button>
```